# Webhook endpoint listener with java

Tags: java, spring-boot, whatsapp

I want to get the webhook from whatsapp businnes api with the messages directly in java.
Is there a way without Node.js ?
Could maybe java spring work ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Java Spring can handle HTTP requests and hence webhooks.
You might want to start with a [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).